# How to delete event source windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell, windows-event-log

I would like to delete an event source in windows 2008.

I don't want to delete the log event, just the source.

How do I do that?

I don't find any command i PowerShell that does that.

```
PS > gcm *EventLog -CommandType cmdlet
CommandType     Name                 Definition
-----------              ----                                       ----------
Cmdlet                 Clear-EventLog                 Clear-EventLog [-LogName] <String[]> [[-Computer...
Cmdlet                 Get-EventLog                   Get-EventLog [-LogName] <String> [[-InstanceId] ...
Cmdlet                 Limit-EventLog                 Limit-EventLog [-LogName] <String[]> [-ComputerN...
Cmdlet                 New-EventLog                 New-EventLog [-LogName] <String> [-Source] <Stri...
Cmdlet                 Remove-EventLog          Remove-EventLog [-LogName] <String[]> [[-Compute...
Cmdlet                 Show-EventLog               Show-EventLog [[-ComputerName] <String>] [-Verbo...
Cmdlet                 Write-EventLog               Write-EventLog [-LogName] <String> [-Source] <St...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Remove-EventLog`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849786.aspx) to unregister one or more event sources:

```
Remove-EventLog -Source "My Custom Source"
Remove-EventLog -Source "ASource","Another one","CustomApp123"
```